# How to change href for homepage to work regardless of current HTML file location

Tags: html, web

I've created the side menu bar of my website in a separate html file that uses jquery to import it to my website's pages. I ran into a problem where I have some html files in a separate folder causing the homepage button link to not work due to it being in a different relative file path:

```
<a href="../../Content/Homepage.htm"><li>Home</li></a>
```

How can I make this href path universal so regardless of the current html file's location, it will always go to my Homepage.htm which is located in the root of my project file.

Comment: "*Homepage.htm which is located in the root of my project file*" It doesn't look like it, are you sure about this fact? Looks like it's in the `/Content` subdirectory.

Comment: Content is just the name of the project folder.

Comment: For more context, my project File is called Content. Inside Content I have Homepage.htm and a folder named Procedures containing htm files alongside subdirectories with other htm files